# Using plot.ly in jupyterlab - graphics does not show

Tags: anaconda, plotly, jupyter-lab

I want to draw 3D PCA with pylot (*Scatter3d*), however the graphics is not showing up in *jupyterlab* only in *jupyter-notebook*.

I've installed the 'jupyterlab_plotly' package and I was able to create an 'jupyterlab_plotly.Plotly object', but I couldn't figure out how to actually include/draw the graphics in the notebook.

I wonder if someone could post a working example of drawing figures in jupyterlab with pyplot.

(The example at the project's git site - https://github.com/gnestor/jupyterlab_plotly- only present an 'jupyterlab_plotly.Plotly object', but not the graphics itself)

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. Looks like the project has moved over here:
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-renderers
Installing with the suggested:
`jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/plotly-extension`
worked for me.

Comment: Here's the link to that page: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-renderers/tree/master/packages/plotly-extension

Answer (score 2):

This is now superseded by `jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly` as per https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#jupyterlab-support-python-35

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @user1561393 describes a good solution.

I want to add that the plotly documentation also covers these steps in some extra detail in their ['Getting started' guide](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/#jupyterlab-support-python-35). This should normally remain up-to date even when some they migrate to newer services (as has happened with their V4).