# plot.ly offline mode in jupyter lab not displaying plots

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter, jupyter-lab

According to the documentation, [offline mode with plot.ly](https://plot.ly/python/offline/) in Jupyter is supposed to work after calling:

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

Now I am trying to show the following plot:

```
trace0 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[10, 15, 13, 17]
)
trace1 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[16, 5, 11, 9]
)

iplot([trace0, trace1])
```

The result is much empty space in the cell output area.

[image]

Why is this not working with Jupyter Lab?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A couple things might be happening. For some reason is your Notebook "Not Trusted?" This will stop the Plotly javascript from rendering anything below.

Another possibility is that you don't have the Plotly extension installed for Jupyter Lab. In Lab, as compared to Notebooks, there are a lot more restrictions on what javascript can execute, so packages need to have extensions installed in order to display anything beneath the cell.

Look for the plotly-extension with
`jupyter labextension list`

and install it if missing with: `jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly`

Comment: It was the missing extension, which is not mentioned in the docs. Thanks.

Comment: This is now superseded by `jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly` as per their ['Getting started' guide](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#jupyterlab-support-python-35).

Comment: @eddygeek I think so too, and I think you'd need restart Jupiter lab after installing it in order for changes to take effect.

Comment: Everything failed and I had to shift back to Jupyter Notebook. Goodbye Lab

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Although I had to install from command line, the built-in gui extension manager did not find this extension by searching

Answer (score 43):

Try changing the renderer:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'iframe' # or 'notebook' or 'colab' or 'jupyterlab'
```

You can loop through the list like this to see what fits you

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

for text in pio.renderers:
    print(text)
    pio.renderers.default = text

    df = px.data.iris()
    fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species")
    fig.show()
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks. For me, using "colab" or "sphinx_gallery" works the best! :)

Comment: This worked for me using `jupyterlab = "^3.1.12"`

Comment: when running this in jupyterlab, oddly enough, the only successful setting was `colab`

Answer (score 15):

Plotly-extension has been deprecated, use another:

```
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly
```

it worked for me and it has no compatibility issues with the latest versions of plotly (currently 4.9.0) / jupyterlab

source: https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/ , https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jupyterlab/plotly-extension

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it will be using HTML to help JupyterLab show figures. One example will be:

```
import plotly.express as px
from IPython.display import HTML

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x='total_bill', y='tip', opacity=0.65,
                 trendline='ols', trendline_color_override='darkblue')
HTML(fig.to_html())
```

Comment: This works for me in Jupyterlab version 3.0.14.

Comment: This worked for me, Jupyterlab v 3.3.2

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Jupyter Lab (Not Jupyter Notebook), you need to install "Jupyter Renderers" extension for Jupyter Lab.
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-renderers

check out the similar topics:
- [Using plot.ly in jupyterlab - graphics does not show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439771/using-plot-ly-in-jupyterlab-graphics-does-not-show)
- [plotly basic example shows no plot in jupyter lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264181/plotly-basic-example-shows-no-plot-in-jupyter-lab)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but when I tried to run the following code, I received an error:

```
$ jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.10.0

An error occured.
ValueError: Please install nodejs >=10.0.0 before continuing. nodejs may be 
installed using conda or directly from the nodejs website.
```

But I ran the "`node -v`" and my version was `v6.13.1`, that means it was supposed to work.

I found the way to solve my problem through this post >> [Conda not recognizing that I have node installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849352/conda-not-recognizing-that-i-have-node-installed)

I installed as recommended in https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/nodejs and it worked well.

I ran all of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge nodejs
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 nodejs
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 nodejs
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 nodejs '
```

Comment: You don't need to run ALL of the commands you listed. Only `conda install -c conda-forge nodejs` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if your Anaconda installed in root directory of Windows, for example: `C:\Anaconda\`
Then this is what worked for me, because I could not run the
`jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly` from my (base) Python.
Therefor, first I ran this in my virtual env: `jupyter labextension list`
Next `jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly`
Once installed and tested in Virtual env,
I copied the `jupyter-labextension-script.py` from Scripts folder under the Virtual Env, and paste it to Scripts folder in my main (Base) Python folder.
Now, `activate base`
Next follow these commands: `jupyter labextension list`
Finally `jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly`

Test your Jupyterlab and you should be able to see your graphs.