# Plotly Table does not show in Jupyter Lab in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter-lab

I try to plot table in Plotly in Python in Jupyter Lab. But my table in plotly does not show in Jupyter Lab, my code is as below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=list(df.columns),
                fill_color='paleturquoise',
                align='left'),
    cells=dict(values=[df.A, df.M, df.R, df.C, df.B, df.S, df.P, df.G, df.U],
               fill_color='lavender',
               align='left'))
])

fig.show()
```

I tried many ways like:

1. `fig.show('notebook')`
2. `fig.show('jupyterlab')`
3. `plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)`
4. `pyo.init_notebook_mode()`

But nothing works, I still do not see my ploytly table in Jupyter Lab, what can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

try with `plotly.offline.iplot(fig)` instead of `fig.show()`

```
import plotly.offline as py_offline

....

py_offline.iplot(fig)
```

Alternatively, you can use `fig.show(renderer='notebook')` check it up here https://plotly.com/python/renderers/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this was your case... it was my one!

I had the very same problem. I mean, I installed plotly directly in the Jupyter Lab, and when I tried it there was only a blank space where the table should be, using the example copied from

`https://plotly.com/python/table/`

After many trials and wandering around I find the comment at [plot.ly offline mode in jupyter lab not displaying plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064245/plot-ly-offline-mode-in-jupyter-lab-not-displaying-plots) by @eddygeek "I think so too, and I think you'd need restart Jupiter lab after installing it in order for changes to take effect." –
Kareem Jeiroudi  Apr 10, 2020 at 17:29

After restarting the Jupyter, things ran nicely!